# TortoiseHg extdiff for certain file type

Tags: tortoisehg

I would like to use the visual diff tool from TortoiseSVN in my TortoiseHg. I found that I can use extdiff in the .ini file like this:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.tortoiseIdiff = C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseIDiff.exe
opts.tortoiseIdiff = /left:"$parent" /lefttile:"$plabel1" /right:"$child" /righttitle:"$clabel" /showinfo
```

But now all my files try to open with TortoiseIDiff.exe when I set it as default. How can I tell TortoiseHg to only use this on certain file extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add instead [extdiff]:

```
[merge-tools]
imgdiff.priority=-100
imgdiff.regkey=Software\TortoiseSVN
imgdiff.regname=Directory
imgdiff.regappend=\bin\TortoiseIDiff.exe
imgdiff.gui=True
imgdiff.diffargs=/left:"$parent" /lefttitle:"$plabel1" /right:"$child" /righttitle:"$clabel" /showinfo

[merge-patterns]
**.png = imgdiff

[diff-patterns]
**.png = imgdiff
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use extension-specific differ without extdiff extension now
2. You **must** to configure TortoiseIDiff as image-only differ, not global

In order to properly use `TortoiseIDiff` inside TortoiseHG, you have

- Define TortoiseIDiff as additional custom diff|merge tool (consult with `hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc` for details and samples): you have to add definition in own `[merge-tools]` section inside global merurial.ini or repo's `.hgrc`
- Assign this diff-tool as differ for image-files in `[diff-patterns]` section (see `hgrc.d\MergePatterns.rc`)